# Why .NET TypeInfo.GetDeclaredField return both public and private fields?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Documentation of TypeInfo.GetDeclaredField method clearly states that it "returns an object that represents the specified **public** field declared by the current type". So I suppose that it should distinguish by public and non-public fields and return "null" for non-public ones ("*the specified field, if found; otherwise, null*", according to the docs). However, if I define both public and private fields in the class, a call to GetDeclaredField on the corresponding TypeInfo object returns field object in both cases.

Is this a bug in documentation or a bug in the implementation? I can hardly believe this is an implementation bug since this is the part of core .NET functionality. So why is it documented in such way?

Comment: I strongly suspect it's a documentation bug. It's the same for methods, properties etc as well though...

Comment: Thank you Jon. I also suspect so.

Comment: MSDN articles on recent additions to the framework are not very good.  You can usually tell from a distance from the very brief description and the lack of any example code, good reasons to question their accuracy.  The reference source is always a good alternative, lets you see that it uses BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly.  So non-public as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Too bad I didn't check the source :-(